# Degree of freedom of Unitary and Skew-Hermitian matrix (solved)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Reading an [article](http://fge.if.usp.br/~tiagops/Coordinate.pdf) (A. Veneziani, T. Pereira, *A note on the volume form in normal matrix space*) I didn't understand this sentence:

"Given a unitary matrix $U$ we may use the representation $U=e^W$ where $W$ is a skew-hermitian matrix $W=-W^*$. For our case, W will be a skew-hermitian matrix which zero diagonal. *This is to equalise the degrees of freedom of $U$*."

I don't understand why we have to force the elements of the diagonals to become zero. The degrees of freedom of a $n*n$ unitary matrix are $n^2$ and the same is true for skew-hermitian matrix ($n(n-1)+n$, being the diagonal elements imaginary).

**Oh, I understood! The author did not consider the unitary group, but the unitary group minus the n-torus. My bad sorry, thanks any way!**

Comment: Surely you can not select all element of a unitary matrix at random? You must have $U*U = I$. Regardless, it would be good to edit the question to include the title of the paper and a link.

Comment: @CarlChristian  Well the degrees of freedom of a unitary matrix are $n^2$ because a general $n*n$ (complex) matrix has $2n^2$ independent elements (real and imaginary part). The constrain $UU^*=1$ gives $n^2$ elements in function of the other. I linked the article.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for clarifying this for me.